# Point Clouds associated with Grid Structures?

Tags: 3d, point-clouds

This [page](http://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Entities) says the following:

point clouds coming from structured/gridded files (such as PTX, DP or FARO) are now associated to a simple grid structure. This structure will mainly be used to export the cloud in a structured format, but it can also be used when computing normals for instance.

- What kind of grids can be associated with a point cloud?
- Are there format standards and definitions for those kinds of grids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a little further on that same page, there is a [explanation of what kind of structures can be associated with a point cloud](http://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Entities#Point_cloud_associated_structures).

However I think that the word "gridded" files might be confusing you.

[As you can read here](https://laserscanningforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=6133): A gridded file format is just a file that contains not only XYZ, RGB and/or intensity information but also some matrix that can be used to generate planar views of scans.

Here is the specification of the [`PTX` format](http://w3.leica-geosystems.com/kb/?guid=5532D590-114C-43CD-A55F-FE79E5937CB2).